# Why I'm the loop is breaking and getting error even after not satisfying the condition?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, break

I've following code snippet:

```
        $aSupportedImages = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
        foreach($vshare as $file) {
          if(!in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $aSupportedImages))
            $errArr = 'File extension of image is wrong';
            echo $errArr;              
            break;
        }
```

The array $vshare is as follows(output of `print_r($vshare);`):

```
Array
      (
          [IMG_0004.jpg] => Array
              (
                  [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo
              )

      )
```

I'm not understanding why always the loop is getting broken and getting error "File extension of image is wrong" even after the file having extension which is present in array `$aSupportedImages`?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You may try `foreach($vshare as $name => $value) { ` and `pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use below code,
as the image name is the `key` of the array, and you were using `value` in your extension check

**EDIT** : As other users said, you are missing `{}` brackets in your `if` condition

**NOTE** : When you want to execute only one statement than you dont neet to use the curly braces. If you want to execute multiple statements than you must wrap the statements into curly braces.

```
   $aSupportedImages = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
    foreach($vshare as $key=> $value) {
      if(!in_array(pathinfo($key, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $aSupportedImages))
        {
             $errArr = 'File extension of image is wrong';
             echo $errArr;              
             break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis {} for if block and check print_r statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket for `if` statement:

```
foreach($vshare as $file) {
    if(!in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $aSupportedImages)) {
        $errArr = 'File extension of image is wrong';
        echo $errArr;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also it's better use `continue` instead of `break`. Break destruct loop and other files don't checked, but continue let check other files and show error only for broken conditions.